# Дайте совет со стороны вашего опыта, с чего бы начали вы? Что бы использовали сами?

Tags: c#, android, unity3d, kotlin, unity3d-android

Я собираюсь в будущем создавать проекты на андроид, в которых все пользователи будут в реальном времени получать информацию с сервера или БД. Мне нужно помощь по поиску информации/книг по этой теме, которые лучше опишут к чему мне готовиться, какие языки использовать, какие плюсы и минусы у этих языков. В общем нужен ваш опыт. Типа когда вы прочтете это, сразу поймете, что бы вы изучили с первую очередь, что во вторую, на что нацелились бы...

Предположим, я делаю игру, в которой все игроки совершают действия в реальном времени. Допустим, что пользователей будет 100.000 (я реалист, и скорее ничего подобного не будет). В моем понимании она будет работать в связке Клиент <--> Сервер <--> База данных. Где в БД(или на сервере?) хранится информация о мире и передается игроку, когда он совершает действие. Хоть технологий в наше время огромное множество,

1. Посоветуйте, на чем в таком случае делать клиент. (C# + Unity? Kotlin?)
2. Изучать ли языки для создания сервера (Go, Python), или может взять какие то готовые и переработать под себя? Или может изучать NodeJS?
3. Использовать какую то особенную БД? Я в целом мало что знаю про их особенности.

Как я и сказал, это всё может выглядеть глупо, потому как я только ищу с чего начать "въезд" в тему. И чтобы не изучать 10 языков, потом разбираться какой лучше подойдет для моих целей, я спрашиваю у вас. Конечно, всё делать я буду не в одиночку. В общем с высоты своего опыта посоветуйте глупому мне, с чего начать, какие книги и т.д. Очень не хватает понимания всех процессов

Comment: Если вы делаете игры под телефон - C#, юнити тут идеален. Если делаете приложения под андроид НЕ связанные с играми - Kotlin. А так я бы посоветовал C#

Comment: @Aarnihauta Огромная благодарность за совет! Начну свой путь с C#.

Comment: Не важно какой выбор вы сделаете, главное его сделать и начать что-то делать. Тогда и половина вопросов отпадет.

Answer (score 0):

Ну во-первых нужна база.
Я бы начал с изучения основ Kotlin - так как это основной язык программирования под андроид с 2017 года. В принципе он умеет делать и серверные запросы и наверное это всё что и пригодиться.
Потом бы, вместе с практикой изучал бы библиотеки для kotlin или java (без разницы, здесь как в PlayStation обратная совсместимасть - на PS4 можно играть в игры для PS3, но не наоборот. В этом примере Kotlin - это PS4)
Если уже и говорить про язык на серверной стороне, то я слышал что Питон хорош в этом и лёгок в обучении, но всё же лучше что-нибудь полегче типа JS
Если выберешь всё-таки JS, то не забудь про AJAX